# I am able to set up to receive emails, but I am unable to upload attachments to onedrive. Please tell me how to upload the file

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I want to store a specific Excel file attached to an email I receive in outlook in a specific folder in onedrive.
(I have the process to store the file in blob, but I want to process the Excel file, so I am thinking of saving it once in onedrive.)

I am able to set up to receive emails, but I am unable to upload attachments to onedrive. Please tell me how to upload the file.
The contents of the Excel file, but there are multiple sheets.

[image: This is an image of a series of flow of receiving a mail, retrieving the attached file, and saving it in an onedrive folder.]

The json looks like this. (partially hidden)

```
{
"id": "/subscriptions/XXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/XXXXXXXX/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/test/workflows/excel_test2",
"name": "test/excel_test2",
"type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/workflows",
"kind": "Stateful",
"location": "XXXXXXXX",
"properties": {
    "files": {
        "workflow.json": {
            "definition": {
                "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
                "actions": {
                    "For_each": {
                        "actions": {
                            "Update_file": {
                                "inputs": {
                                    "body": "@base64ToBinary(items('For_each')?['contentBytes'])",
                                    "host": {
                                        "connection": {
                                            "referenceName": "onedriveforbusiness"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "method": "put",
                                    "path": "/datasets/default/files/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('filebox\\raw\\*.xlsm'))}"
                                },
                                "runAfter": {
                                    "Getting Attachments_(V2)": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                },
                                "runtimeConfiguration": {
                                    "contentTransfer": {
                                        "transferMode": "Chunked"
                                    }
                                },
                                "type": "ApiConnection"
                            },
                            "Getting Attachments_(V2)": {
                                "inputs": {
                                    "host": {
                                        "connection": {
                                            "referenceName": "office365"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "method": "get",
                                    "path": "/codeless/v1.0/me/messages/@{encodeURIComponent(triggerBody()?['id'])}/attachments/@{encodeURIComponent(items('For_each')?['id'])}"
                                },
                                "runAfter": {},
                                "type": "ApiConnection"
                            }
                        },
                        "foreach": "@triggerBody()?['attachments']",
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "Foreach"
                    }
                },
                "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                "outputs": {},
                "triggers": {
                    "When you receive a new email_(V3)": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "fetch": {
                                "method": "get",
                                "pathTemplate": {
                                    "template": "/v3/Mail/OnNewEmail"
                                },
                                "queries": {
                                    "fetchOnlyWithAttachment": true,
                                    "folderPath": "Id::XXXXXXXX=",
                                    "importance": "Any",
                                    "includeAttachments": true
                                }
                            },
                            "host": {
                                "connection": {
                                    "referenceName": "office365"
                                }
                            },
                            "subscribe": {
                                "body": {
                                    "NotificationUrl": "@{listCallbackUrl()}"
                                },
                                "method": "post",
                                "pathTemplate": {
                                    "template": "/GraphMailSubscriptionPoke/$subscriptions"
                                },
                                "queries": {
                                    "fetchOnlyWithAttachment": true,
                                    "folderPath": "Id::XXXXXXXX=",
                                    "importance": "Any"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "metadata": {
                            "Id::XXXXXXXX=": "XXXXXXXX_1"
                        },
                        "splitOn": "@triggerBody()?['value']",
                        "type": "ApiConnectionNotification"
                    }
                }
            },
            "kind": "Stateful"
        }
    },
    "flowState": 2,
    "health": {
        "state": 1
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve your requirement is to create a file in OneDrive with the same name as you are receiving from outlook. Below is the flow of my logic app.

[image]

Below is the mail I'm receiving in my outlook

[image]

**RESULTS:**

***Results in Logic Apps***

[image]

***Results in One drive***

[image]